# Logging and Fetching Run Parameters in AzureML

Tags: azure, mlflow, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am able to log and fetch metrics to AzureML using Run.log, however, I need a way to also log run parameters, like Learning Rate, or Momentum. I can't seem to find anything in the AzureML Python SDK documentation to achieve this. However, if I use MLflow's mlflow.log_param, I am able to log parameters, and they even nicely show up on the AzureML Studio Dashboard (bottom right of the image):

[image]

Again, I am able to fetch this using MLflow's get_params() function, but I can't find a way to do this using just AzureML's Python SDK. Is there a way to do this directly using `azureml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retrieving of log run parameters like **Learning Rate, or Momentum** is not possible with **AzureML** alone. Because it was tied with **MLFlow** and **azureml-core**. without those two involvements, we cannot retrieve the log run parameters.

```
pip install azureml-core mlflow azureml-mlflow
```

Need to install these three for getting run parameters. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-log-view-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

In AzureML Python SDK v1, you can save and get metrics from the Run object.

First find the run id (either in the UI or with the SDK)

```
from azureml.core.run import Run
run = Run(experiment=<experiment_name>, run_id=<run_id>)
```

Second, use the `get_metrics` method from the `run` object

```
run.get_metrics(name=None, recursive=False, run_type=None, populate=False)
```

Documentation:

- [Run class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py)
- [get_metrics()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-run-run-get-metrics)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question was about logging Parameters, not Metrics.